# Linear congruences $2X\equiv9\pmod{26},\pmod{25}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

> May double that of a natural number let rest $9$ when divided by $26$? And when divided by $25$?

I tried:

> $$2X\equiv9\pmod{26}$$ As $(26,2)=2$ and $2\nmid9$ then the congruence linear not admits solution. So far, everything ok!
>
> However in $$2X\equiv9\pmod{25}$$ As $(25,2)=1$ we assume that the congruence a single solution.
>
> I tried to find the solution using Diophantine equations, however, observe $$2X\equiv9\pmod{25}\Longrightarrow25\mid2X-9\Longrightarrow\\2X-9=25k\Longrightarrow\fbox{$2X-25k=9$}$$
>
> I'm on the right track?
>
> How do I proceed if yes.

Comment: Can you reword the question please? It is very hard to understand.

Comment: @copper.hat I want to find the solution to $$2X\equiv9\pmod{25}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$2 \cdot 13 \equiv 26 \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$$

So, multiplication by 13 cancels $2$ in $\pmod{25}$.

**Alternately** Use the Extended Euclidian Algorithm to solve $2a+25b=1$ and multiply it by $9$ to get a solution to your Diophantine equation.

Comment: Not got the idea, use Diophantine equations again?

Comment: Yes, then $$x=17$$

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too complicated, I'm afraid. $2X\equiv9\pmod{25}$ is equivalent to $2X\equiv34\pmod{25}.$ Since $(2,25)=1,$ then we can conclude that $2$ has a multiplicative inverse *modulo* $25$ ($13$, in particular, but it isn't necessary to know this to complete the problem). This allows us to effectively "divide by $2$" on both sides of the congruence $2X\equiv34\pmod{25},$ giving us the answer.

Comment: Not got the idea, use Diophantine equations again?

Comment: From a Diophantine point of view, note that the following are equivalent: $$\begin{align}2X-9 &= 25k\\13(2X-9) &= 13(25k)\\26X-117 &= 25\cdot13k\\X-17+25\cdot(X-4) &= 25\cdot13k\\X-17 &= 25(13k-X+4)\end{align}$$